# How does a NFT look like on the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, nft

Are all NFT's created equal in terms of a contract template? How does a NFT look like on the ethereum blockchain? Is it basically a ERC-20 token but with only 1 supply? What are some examples of this?

Comment: it is a standard but anyone can deviate from the standard if he wants to. And many do.

Comment: I wouldn't say "anyone can deviate from the standard". The standard dictates certain function signatures, for example, which *must* exist. But implementation can be whatever and can add extra functionality

Answer (score 1):

No they are not ERC20. Also, they are not ERC20 compatible. They have similar functionalities, but a bit different - plus some extra stuff.

It's actually a bit tricky to find a full flat implementation of ERC721, since it's always used in a modular way: various contracts (and interfaces) are inherited which combined make the full functionality. The most famous reference implementation is probably from OpenZeppelin: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol

Not all ERC721 contracts are equal. All of them have to implement the minimum standard functionality, but many of them have also some extra functionality for making things easier.

Comment: any examples of how this would look like on etherscan?

Comment: https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d#code